# CakePHP: Make Dashboard page by get data from other Controllers

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.3

I have researched for this solution all month but I didn't get the right answer for my page. Please take a look and give me suggestions.

I have the admin page and the view is Dashboard.

I have tables are Staffs, Customers, Comments, Contacts....

I created these page to show data on view successfully for each of them.

NOW, I want to make the dashboard page to view each 5 top new Staffs, Customers, Comments....were being added to system. The summary page. My Dashboard page will be my main page (when access the domain, it will direct to dashboard page).

**My question are:**

1. Where should I create the Dashboard page in?
2. How can I take the data from Staff Controllers, Customers Controller....in the dashboard page. Dashboard page is not include in view of these above controllers.

***I use cakephp 1.3***

Please give me the best suggestion for this. Thank everyone much !

Answer (score 1):

First of all it depends upon the way you wanna go ahead:

1) Where should I create the Dashboard page in?

Its totally upto you where you want to create the page, but it should ideally be the page to be redirected after the admin login.(BTW its a foolish question to be asked.)

2) How can I take the data from Staff Controllers, Customers Controller....in the dashboard page. Dashboard page is not include in view of these above controllers.

You can do that in 2 ways:

a) Create common functions for these in their respective model and just call those into your single function created for dashboard.

b) Create functions in their respective controller and import the controller and use these methods in the dashboard function(But avoid this approach as long as you can as it will load unnecessary controller class files).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I try to do like your suggestion. Now I make Dashboard page in app/views/pages/dashboard.ctp and I tried (b) solution to do. But I don't know how to import and call another function in conntroller on Dashboard page. Please help me more detail.

Comment: I can help you out but I guess it would be better for you to search for it. It will make you to explore thing out there more. If you still face any issue doing that you are always welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, that was kind of. I still want to researched by myself to get more exp...but in this situation I have research more than a month. But I can't get it. The logic, the way to solve I thought before I ask, but I don't have enough technical to apply. That why I go to Stack and post a Question like this. You are so kind of if give me more details.

Comment: Great, I will try to help you out.

I will request you to try out 2.a rather than 2.b since in MVC, always think of 'fat models, skinny controllers'.

Comment: App::import('Controller', 'Users');
$Users = new UsersController;
$Users->constructClasses();

Now using the object $Users you can call any  function inside your Users Class.

Above way you can import one controller into another. Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry, I am too stupid. I find out about the App::import('Controller', 'Users') before you said but I don't know where should I put it to. Now I just have only Dashboard.ctp. Before, I tried to create Dashboard_Controller and Model to use. But it is not successful. For make it easy. Now I have Staffs_controller.php and top_new_staffs() function to get 5 new staffs in the board. So now I will add the App::import('Controller', 'Staffs'); ahead of Dashboard.ctp and call the top_new_staffs() to get data. Is it right?

Comment: Yes you can do that in ctp also but its not the right way. Use it in controller function rendering the dashboard page by setting the data using $this->set(). Hope it helps you.

Comment: I FOUND IT follow this http://book.cakephp.org/1.1/en/controllers.html I use requestAction
Destination: just return data from database like function ACB(){return $this->Staff->find("all");}. In Dashboard Controller function index(){$this->set('newstaffs', $this->requestAction('/staffs/ABC'));}. Fianlly I found the way to retrive data from another controller. Thank for your help @Vivek Shukla

Comment: @TommyDo - Yeah that is also a way out there to do it but using it for large data interaction is not a good coding practice, I guess. Though I might be wrong but I personally do not prefer this for these kind of activities, it can be used as subsidiary though. BTW you are always welcome. :)

Comment: I will consider about your suggestion. I am very new in CakePHP so if I have something I have to bother you again. :v